# How to make the package to search in remaining sys.path, if importError occur?

Tags: python-3.6

I am trying to import package `import http.client` which exist in the directory `/usr/lib/python3.6` but when I tried to import that to the python script file and then execute that file then it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'http.client'`

I tried further debugging and found that the order of sys.path is the culprit.

```
import sys
print ('\n'.join(sys.path))
import http
print (http.__file__)
import http.client
```

The output was :
for `print ('\n'.join(sys.path))`

```
/root/.pycharm_helpers/pydev
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fire
/root/.pycharm_helpers/third_party/thriftpy
/root/.pycharm_helpers/pydev
/usr/lib/python3.6
and so on...
```

for `print (http.__file__)`
`/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fire`

Since the `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fire` is before the actual path `/usr/lib/python3.6` and there also exist "http" directory but there is no client file which is causing this error.

Now my question is how to include `import http.client` this and if the importError happen then it should try to find them the remaining `sys.path` such that even if it couldn't able to find in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fire` it should try next and when the `/usr/lib/python3.6` turn comes it will be imported successfully.

Or Is there any better approach to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can name the package from which you want to import the module. 
So something like `from http import client as http.client` will work. 
Also not that after the as you can call the module however you want like hc for example and shortness as you will later in code refer to the `http.client.somefunction()` with `hc.somefunction()`